# Unrelated "protected" entry in stack trace

Tags: scala, stack-trace

Copied from the scala-user list, where it has received no loving...

The following elements are reported to be in the stack during an
exception:

```
at mypackage.MessageManagerDAO.update(MessageManagerDAO.java:100)
at mypackage.QueueDao.protected$update(QueueDao.scala:58)
at mypackage.QueueDao$$anon$1$$anonfun$to$1.apply(QueueDao.scala:131)
at mypackage.QueueDao$$anon$1$$anonfun$to$1.apply(QueueDao.scala:129)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:185)
at mypackage.QueueDao$$anon$1.to(QueueDao.scala:129)
```

The curious thing is, line 131 is unrelated to line 58. Line 58 has no
business in this stack. The only things in common between the two
entries are that they both call the abstract super class method
MessageManagerDAO.update (Java) and that the logic flow is similar.

What does the `protected` signify? And why could it be appearing in my
stack trace?

I'm using Scala 2.8.1

Here are some code snippets:

```
57: maybeQueue.foreach{queueDef =>
58:   val updateCount = update(SQL.updateLastReadAttempt, queueDef.category, queueDef.host)
59:   if (updateCount == 0) update(SQL.insertLastReadAttempt, queueDef.category, queueDef.host)
60:  }

129: message.relatedId.foreach{relatedId =>
130:   val updated = update(SQL.incrementMessageCount, relatedId, qd.category, qd.host)
131:   if (updated == 0) update(SQL.insertMessageCount, relatedId, qd.category, qd.host)
132:  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a direct answer, but I hope this will be useful:

The Scala compiler sometimes translates your code in ways that are hard to understand, especially if you use closures and other things for which there is no direct equivalent in Java.

Try compiling your code with `scalac -print`, that will show you what the Scala compiler makes out of your source code. You'd have to search through the output to see exactly what happens with the calls in your code.